# SQL Query, Need help using "contains" and "does not contain"

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with how to write an `SQL` statement.  This what I am trying to say, this clearly is not `SQL` format but for purpose of understanding the request:

```
SELECT     *
FROM       $A$
WHERE      marketprovider_1 OR  marketprovider_2 OR  marketprovider_3 OR  marketprovider4 OR marketprovider_5 CONTAIN ‘data’ AND  ‘tv’
AND
WHERE marketprovider_1 OR marketprovider_2 OR marketprovider_3 OR marketprovider4 OR marketprovider_5 DO NOT CONTAIN  “vios” OR ‘phone” OR  “uverse’;
```

My failed attempt at the query:

```
SELECT * FROM  $A$
WHERE CONTAINS(marketprovider_1, ‘data’) OR CONTAINS(marketprovider_2, ‘data’) OR CONTAINS(marketprovider_3, ‘data’) OR CONTAINS(marketprovider_4, ‘data’) OR CONTAINS(marketprovider_5, ‘data’)  
AND
WHERE CONTAINS(marketprovider_1, ‘tv’) OR CONTAINS(marketprovider_2, ‘tv) OR CONTAINS(marketprovider_3, ‘tv) OR CONTAINS(marketprovider_4 ‘tv) OR CONTAINS(marketprovider_5, ‘tv)
AND
WHERE NOT IN(marketprovider_1, ‘vios’) OR NOT IN (marketprovider_2, ‘vios’) OR NOT IN (marketprovider_3, ‘vios’) OR NOT IN (marketprovider_4, ‘vios’) OR NOT IN (marketprovider_5, ‘vios’)  
AND
WHERE NOT IN (marketprovider_1, ‘phone’) OR NOT IN (marketprovider_2, ‘phone’) OR NOT IN (marketprovider_3, ‘phone’) OR NOT IN (marketprovider_4 ‘phone’) OR NOT IN (marketprovider_5, ‘phone’)
AND
WHERE NOT IN (marketprovider_1, ‘uverse’) OR NOT IN (marketprovider_2, ‘uverse’) OR NOT IN (marketprovider_3, ‘uverse’) OR NOT IN (marketprovider_4 ‘uverse’) OR NOT IN (marketprovider_5, ‘uverse’)
```

Comment: How about normalizing the database? Having 5 columns that contain 5 occurences of the same type of data will soon get out of hand... especially if you have NULL values in the way ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of valid SQL `WHERE` clause syntax that implements the predicates you described.

```
WHERE (  ( marketprovider_1 LIKE '%data%' AND marketprovider_1 LIKE '%tv%' )
      OR ( marketprovider_2 LIKE '%data%' AND marketprovider_2 LIKE '%tv%' )
      OR ( marketprovider_3 LIKE '%data%' AND marketprovider_3 LIKE '%tv%' )
      OR ( marketprovider_4 LIKE '%data%' AND marketprovider_4 LIKE '%tv%' )
      OR ( marketprovider_5 LIKE '%data%' AND marketprovider_5 LIKE '%tv%' )
      )
  AND
  NOT (  marketprovider_1 LIKE '%vios%'
      OR marketprovider_2 LIKE '%vios%'
      OR marketprovider_3 LIKE '%vios%'
      OR marketprovider_4 LIKE '%vios%'
      OR marketprovider_5 LIKE '%vios%'

      OR marketprovider_1 LIKE '%phone%'
      OR marketprovider_2 LIKE '%phone%'
      OR marketprovider_3 LIKE '%phone%'
      OR marketprovider_4 LIKE '%phone%'
      OR marketprovider_5 LIKE '%phone%'

      OR marketprovider_1 LIKE '%uverse%'
      OR marketprovider_2 LIKE '%uverse%'
      OR marketprovider_3 LIKE '%uverse%'
      OR marketprovider_4 LIKE '%uverse%'
      OR marketprovider_5 LIKE '%uverse%'
      )
```

(I'm assuming that by "contains" you mean that a particular string occurs within the column value, and by "does not contain" means you want to check that a particular string does not occur anywhere within the column contents.)

The `LIKE` operator is one way to check whether a particular string occurs within another string, the `'%'` is a wildcard character that matches zero, one or more characters. For example:

```
''           LIKE '%tv%'  => 0
'feefifofum' LIKE '%tv%'  => 0
'tv'         LIKE '%tv%'  => 1
'tvfifofum'  LIKE '%tv%'  => 1
'fee tv fo'  LIKE '%tv%'  => 1
NULL         LIKE '%tv%'  => NULL
```

---

The example WHERE clause (above) checks for a single marketprovider_N column that contains both the string `'data'` and the string `'tv'`; it's possible this differs from what you meant to specify.

If you meant (instead) that if any of the marketprovider_N columns contained 'data' and any of the marketprovider_N columns contained 'tv', that would be a slightly different WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (  ( marketprovider_1 LIKE '%data%' )
      OR ( marketprovider_2 LIKE '%data%' )
      OR ( marketprovider_3 LIKE '%data%' )
      OR ( marketprovider_4 LIKE '%data%' )
      OR ( marketprovider_5 LIKE '%data%' )
      )
  AND (  ( marketprovider_1 LIKE '%tv%' )
      OR ( marketprovider_2 LIKE '%tv%' )
      OR ( marketprovider_3 LIKE '%tv%' )
      OR ( marketprovider_4 LIKE '%tv%' )
      OR ( marketprovider_5 LIKE '%tv%' )
      ) 
  AND
  NOT (  marketprovider_1 LIKE '%vios%'
      OR marketprovider_2 LIKE '%vios%'
      OR marketprovider_3 LIKE '%vios%'
      OR marketprovider_4 LIKE '%vios%'
      OR marketprovider_5 LIKE '%vios%'

      OR marketprovider_1 LIKE '%phone%'
      OR marketprovider_2 LIKE '%phone%'
      OR marketprovider_3 LIKE '%phone%'
      OR marketprovider_4 LIKE '%phone%'
      OR marketprovider_5 LIKE '%phone%'

      OR marketprovider_1 LIKE '%uverse%'
      OR marketprovider_2 LIKE '%uverse%'
      OR marketprovider_3 LIKE '%uverse%'
      OR marketprovider_4 LIKE '%uverse%'
      OR marketprovider_5 LIKE '%uverse%'
      )
```

Anything beyond this, and we're just guessing at permutations of how the specification could be interpreted. Example data, and identifying whether the row should be returned or not, would narrow down the specification.

e.g. which of these rows should be returned...

```
 marketprovider_1 marketprovider_2 marketprovider_3 marketprovider_4 marketprovider_5 
 ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------------
 data tv coffee   NULL             NULL             NULL             NULL 
 data             phone            tv               NULL             NULL 
 data             tv               NULL             NULL             NULL 
 tv               tv               tv               NULL             NULL
 data             netflix          net              NULL             NULL 
 mountain dew     phone            uverse           cable            netflix
 amazon           hulu             no uverse        wifi             roku
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
marketprovider_1 like ('%data%')
```

Where the % is a wildcard.  You can use NOT LIKE for the opposite.

The IN clause you are using is for searching for lists of things.  An example is:

```
marketprovider_1 in ('data','this','that')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can do it making use of `LIKE` and `NOT LIKE`:

```
SELECT     *
FROM       $A$
WHERE      (marketprovider_1 OR  marketprovider_2 OR  marketprovider_3 OR  marketprovider4 
OR         marketprovider_5 LIKE ‘%data%’)
AND        (marketprovider_1 OR  marketprovider_2 OR  marketprovider_3 OR  marketprovider4 
OR         marketprovider_5 LIKE ‘%tv%’)
AND        (marketprovider_1 OR marketprovider_2 OR marketprovider_3 OR marketprovider4 OR marketprovider_5 NOT LIKE '%vios%') 
AND         (marketprovider_1 OR marketprovider_2 OR marketprovider_3 OR marketprovider4 OR marketprovider_5 NOT LIKE '%phone%')
AND         (marketprovider_1 OR marketprovider_2 OR marketprovider_3 OR marketprovider4 OR marketprovider_5 NOT LIKE '%uverse%')
```

Comment: Are you sure that "col1 OR col2 ... OR coln LIKE '...'" is supported syntax?

Comment: @Frazz I'm not completely sure as I have not faced such a scenario. Quite honestly, the design seems a bit out of place for me. *Ideally, these values should have been in separate rows rather than separate columns*. It would have refined the design as well as made the querying much easier making use of `IN` clause.

Comment: @Frazz Having said that, if this doesn't work, the individual comparisons of columns will certainly work (`col1 LIKE '%whatever%' OR col2 LIKE '%whatever%' OR col3 LIKE '%whatever%'`).

Comment: @Frazz I didn't write it that way (which certainly does work) as that would have bloated this query rendering it  *hard to read and understand*. I just wanted to convey the idea.